# WinSock - get local IP address in long

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm using c++ and winsock. I need to get ip address of local machine in long. Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: I found something like this: http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/examples/ipaddr.html but it is a little bit complicated. Is there any single function what returns ip address in LONG?

Comment: no there isn't. but keep in mind a long won't accommodate an IPv6 address.

Comment: One problem you will see is that there may not be one local IP address - there may be several. I guess the following won't help: `long int local_ip = 16777343;` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it is a IPv4 address, you can do with binary operations, since long has 4 bytes

```
void ipLong2String(int ipLong, char &ipStr) {
    ipStr.clear();
    ipStr << ((ipLong & 0xF000) >> 12) << "." 
            << ((ipLong & 0x0F00) >> 8) << "." 
            << ((ipLong & 0x00F0) >> 04 << "." 
            << (ipLong & 0x000F);
}
```

With IPv6 won't be possible.